# What did Sam give Gilly?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Right before the Night's Watch left the house in [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) S02E03, Sam gave Gilly something, but I'm not entirely sure what it was.  It was something his mom gave to him.

What did he give to Gilly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He gave Gilly a thimble that once belonged to his mother. It's the only thing of his mother's that he currently possesses. When Gilly refuses to take it since it's such a precious item, Sam insists that she's only keeping it safe until he returns from the ranging.